# How do CLR Enumerables downcast Generics

Tags: c#, generics, enumerable, downcast

... and can I do it?

So I wanted to implement an EnumerableSubset class for dealing with pagination results within the API:

```
public interface IEnumerableSubset<T> : IEnumerable<T>{
  int Total {get;}
}
public class ListSubset<T> : List<T>, IEnumerableSubset<T>{
  public int Total {get;}

  ListSubset(IEnumerable<T> items, int total){
    AddRange(items);
    Total = total;
  }
}
```

So downcasting generics works with CLR enumerables like List:

```
public IEnumerable<IMyResultObject> GetResults(int skip, int top){
  //return interface but pass class type for deserialization
  var results = GetResults<MyResultObject>(skip,top);
  //results is IEnumerable<MyResultObject>

  return results;
}
```

but not for downcasting generics works with my type:

```
public IEnumerableSubset<IMyResultObject> GetResults(int skip, int top){
  //return interface but pass class type for deserialization
  var results = GetResults<MyResultObject>(skip,top);
  //results is IEnumerableSubset<MyResultObject>

  return results;
}
```

"Invalid Cast" compiler error.

I have to create a new instance of the ListSubset(results, results.Total) that has already been instanciated in GetResults.

So my question is: How does List manage to downcast the generic type and can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your interface to be *invariant* in `T`. You should declare it to be *covariant* in `T`, like `IEnumerable` does:

```cs
public interface IEnumerableSubset<out T> : IEnumerable<T>
```

At that point, it should work.

For more information on generic variance in C#, see the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance).

Comment: Thank you.  I never knew what those declarations did, even to the point of ignoring Resharpers prompts.  I'll give that link a good read ^_^